# Dota2 will not load with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, games, steam

When starting Dota 2 in Steam, the 'preparing to launch' window pops up, disappears, but game will not load. System process shows the game as running, but uses very little memory, and no CPU.
When running the game via terminal, this error represents itself (towards the bottom):

```
Game update: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 11725, IP 0.0.0.0:0 ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/roger/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 11725 for game ID 570
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/roger/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
/bin/bash: /home/roger/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
pid 11730 != 11729, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/roger/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 11726 for game ID 570
>>> Adding process 11729 for game ID 570
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/roger/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 11731 for game ID 570
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 570
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198022088125 [API loaded yes]
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Setting Steam ID:  76561198022088125
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 373300
>>> Adding process 11732 for game ID 570
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

[image]

Helllpppppp!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Run steam using:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

Comment: What's the output of `echo $LIB`? Probably in most cases the shared object library is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`